# How to call parent's scope function with mixed arguments?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, isolate-scope

This is my case -- I have directive with isolated scope and I would like to call function from parent's scope with **mixed** arguments. Mixed -- meaning, one argument comes from the directive, the other comes from the parent.

In case of arguments coming from directive, I could bind that function with `<` and use it, in case of arguments coming from parent's scope, I could bind entire function call with `&`.

I am thinking about two approaches -- one, would simulate currying, call the function with parent's arguments which would return a function accepting directive arguments. Second -- somehow introduce directive variables in the parent's scope, so I could write:

```
<my-directive on-alarm="emergency(parent_var,dir_var)"/>
```

I like the second one better. But I don't know how to do it, i.e. how to introduce directive variables into parent's scope -- without doing a manual "reverse" binding, like:

```
<my-directive for_sake_of_calling="dir_var" on-alarm="emergency(parent_var,dir_var)"/>
```

But those are more like my guesses -- the **main question** is: how to call parent's function with mixed arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by doing the following:

First, setup up the main application HTML,

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
        Emergency text: {{vm.emergencyText}}
        <my-directive on-alarm="vm.emergency(vm.parentVar, directiveVar)"></my-directive>
    </div>
</body>
```

You'll notice that the `on-alarm` callback contains a reference to the `vm.parentVar` variable which just refers to `MainCtrl.parentVar`, and `directiveVar` which will come from the directive itself.

Now we can create our main controller:

```
angular.module('app', []);

angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function () {
    // Initialise the emergency text being used in the view.
    this.emergencyText = '';
    // Define our parent var, which is a parameter called to the emergency function.
    this.parentVar = 'This is an emergency';

    // Define the emergency function, which will take in the parent 
    // and directive text, as specified from the view call 
    // vm.emergency(vm.parentVar, directiveVar).
    this.emergency = function (parentText, directiveText) {
      this.emergencyText = parentText + ' ' + directiveText;
    }.bind(this);
  });
```

Finally, we will create the directive.

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
      scope: {
        onAlarm: '&'
      },
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.onAlarm({ directiveVar: 'from myDirective' });
      }
    }
  });
```

The magic happens after we call `scope.onAlarm({ directiveVar: 'from myDirective' });`. This call tells angular that the alarm callback function (emergency) will have access to `directiveVar`, which we referenced earlier in the view through `on-alarm="vm.emergency(vm.parentVar, directiveVar)"`. Behind the scenes, angular will correctly resolve the parentVar scope to MainCtrl and the directiveVar scope to the directive through its $parse service.

Here's a full [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/CsxA1kKugRdbMK81BTJE?p=preview).

Comment: Wow! Thank you for such thorough answer, pity I can only upvote you once :-).

Comment: Glad I could help!